# CSS: ::after hiding behind element on the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and in my administration I am trying to make this navbar to have an **arrow** on it's active state. At the moment I put some arrow there but the problem is that it is hiding behind the main content.

I used position and z-index on every element on the right(main content) but it doesn't want to show. This navigation is on the left side.

Here is the code to show the arrow:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active::after
{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
  right: 0px;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  z-index: 2;
  border-left-color: #000;
}
```

This is my structure:

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      ....
    </nav>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
     ....
    </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Here is what I have for #wrapper and #page-wrapper. I gave them z-index: -1 and some position and still didn't work :(

```
#wrapper 
{
  padding-left: 0;
}

#page-wrapper 
{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}
```

Any suggestions ??

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the arrow on the `.active > a` instead:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active a:after {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left:5px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  z-index: 2;
  border-left-color: #fff;
}
```

You're adding it on the list item but since the links are blocks, it's going to push it out. Put it on the link itself.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/cocedu/1/edit